# What is wrong with my Django templating use of if's?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
{% for url in urls %}
    <a id="URL_url_{{ url.id }}" class="edit_rightclick"
      title="RIGHT click to edit."
      href="{% if ":" not in url.url %}http://{% endif %}{{ url.url }}">{{ url.url }}</a>
    <span class="delete" id="URL_{{ url.id }}">&amp;#10008;</span> &nbsp;
{% endfor %}
```

The heuristic is intended to prepend the value of a partial or complete URL like google.com, under the assumption that sometimes people will paste a full browser URL, and sometimes people will type out google.com and never type 'http://'.

The templating engine is complaining that '{% if ":" not in url.url %}' is invalid syntax. What is the correct syntax / approach here?

Comment: Why don't you normalize it in your serverside logic instead of the template?

Comment: http:// is ugly. I can store URI's with full address in the template, or I could make my code more complicated by storing a display URL and a live-use URL. As is, the 20-30 character piece of code I want to debug is probably less debugging than refactoring things on the server side so it can keep track of all this.

Comment: You won't be account for `https://` links, right?

Comment: https:// is already dealt with by the conditional, which checks for the presence of a colon as a heuristic and will catch HTTPS URL's and store and produce them correctly. The prepending http:// where the protocol is, is an appropriate basic behavior; people who just habitually type jonathanscorner.com probably want http://jonathanscorner.com/, not https://jonathanscorner.com:8443/

Comment: I've run into a similar error with another if conditional: Are dotted links a problem? Why are those two conditionals, "{% if ":" not in url.url %}" and "{% if time_zone.0 == entity.time_zone %}". I'd like to know why these conditionals are no longer respected, throwing a syntax error.

Comment: I think you are mixing single quotes and quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a filter for this:

```
href="{{ ulr.url|urlize }}"
```

Remember to check here before to build your own (look for urlize):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

---

I think a better approach would be to the save the URLs as absolute ones within the admin and strip "**http://**" when showing the link...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using inline template statements or template filters, you could create a method/property on the model to handle the url creation logic. Assuming your Url is a model:

```
class Url(models.model):
    url = model.TextField()

    @property
    def full_url(self):
        if ":" not in url.url:
            ....
        return full_url
```

And use directly in the templates

```
    href="{{ url.full_url }}">{{ url.url }}</a>
```

The templates stay clean and free of "business logic" which can be a good approach e.g. if you have designers creating html/css templates

edit: This also frees you up to perform more advanced logic in the full_url property (like checking for spam, broken links, etc)

Comment: "This also frees you up to perform more advanced logic in the full_url property (like checking for spam, broken links, etc)" you can do that in a filter as well. If that gets complicated - the business logic shouldn't be in the Url class or templatetags module anyway. I know both approach are good but I personally prefer to keep anything heritating from models.model really simple (no template or business logic there).

Comment: If it is strictly a matter of transforming isolated chunks of data from one format into another for rendering to the template, then filters are definitely the way to to go. If data will be accessed by other means (e.g. if the model is used to create a python API that will be accessed without templates) a model property is best practice.