# What is wrong with my use of conditionals in Django templating?

Tags: django, django-templates

I asked what was wrong with my conditionals in [What is wrong with my Django templating use of if's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005757/what-is-wrong-with-my-django-templating-use-of-ifs) and so far every response has been, "Here's how you can code more pythonically for the specimen I gave. What they did not do is even hint at why my conditional was wrong and could be improve.

"{% if ":" not in url.url %}" and "{% if time_zone.0 == entity.time_zone %}" are both getting "'if' statement improperly formatted" errors. What is this? How can I adjust the conditionals so that they don't crash.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: try this: `href='{% if ":" not in url.url %}http://{% endif %}{{ url.url }}'>`

Comment: I can confirm that both statements work for me in Django 1.5. I don't see another reason this would be broken than @Emily's guess that you're using an old Django. (@Fernando: the fact that he's nesting " quotes inside " quotes doesn't matter because one set is in html and one is in the tag, though I agree that I'd probably write it that way in practice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it sounds like you might be using an older version of Django (<1.2) where these constructs are not yet supported. In Django <1.2, you'd have to use (for example) `{% ifequal time_zone.0 entity.time_zone %}` instead of `{% if time_zone.0 == entity.time_zone %}`.

If this is indeed the problem, you could upgrade Django if that's possible, or you could use [this smartif templatetag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/), which implements comparison operations as in Django >= 1.2. That link includes instructions for how to use it. You might need to do a custom filter or another approach to get the `not in` functionality though, because it doesn't look like smart_if implements that.

Comment: OP should definitely upgrade. 1.1 is four years old.

Comment: I was running, or thought I was running, a fresh 1.5.1 install, courtesy of pip.